# How to handle text selection in NSTextField

Tags: cocoa, selection, nstextfield

probably this is documented somewhere but i just can't find how to 
handle the event of text selection in a NSTextField,
i wan't to respond to the event of the user highlighting some text,
i wan't to get the selected text and do something with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to fix the problem by subclassing `NSTextField` and overriding `- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(NSNotification *)aNotification`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `<NSTextFieldDelegate>`, specifically 
`-textView:willChangeSelectionFromCharacterRange:toCharacterRange:`.

Comment: Thanks but that seems to be related to the `<NSTextViewDelegate>` to an `NSTextView` but im looking for the same behaviour but for an `<NSTextField>`